# Showing items from one layer based on values in another layer

Tags: qgis

I have a few points layers each showing the locations of particular facilities. I have two layers with polygons buffering from centre and from boundary of a site. I would like the correct buffer to appear should a certain set of points be shown on a map i.e if nursery points are shown on map then only the 1Km buffers will show, if I replace the nursery layer with schools layer, the 1Km buffers are removed and replaced by the 2Km buffers.

I think this would be controlled by 'data derived' expressions but I don't know where to start!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way to achieve your goal, but its working. I suppose you have two layers `pointA` and `pointB` as well as a polygon layer `buffers`. Buffer feature have an attribute `width` with well known values, say 1000, when buffer should be related to layerA, and 2000/layerB.

[image: situation in the beginning]

Now when you uncheck layer `pointA` it should be unvisible, and `buffers` should be filtered such that only buffers with `width = 2000` should be visible. When you check `pointA` again, it gets visible and `pointB` not. Same with `pointB`.

[image]

I have modelled this behaviour evaluating the emitted signal, whenever the layer tree changes. If it changes then a handler is called. This handler checks, which layer changes into which state, sets the filter on buffers, and sets the other layer into the opposite state. To not step into an infinite loop, the handler disables itself in the beginning, and enables itself at the end of each call.

Layer names and buffer widths are given in a dict to reflect possible parameter groups. If this should be more flexible, introduce individual variables.

```py
# Qt constants come from this module
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

# disconnect handler, only necessary during testing
iface.layerTreeView().model().dataChanged.disconnect()

# handler
def switch_buffers(index_ul, index_lr):
    # some variables packed into a dict, best outside def as global variable
    states = {'pointA': [1000, 'pointB', 2000], 'pointB': [2000, 'pointA', 1000]}
    # temporarily disconnect handler
    iface.layerTreeView().model().dataChanged.disconnect()

    # get model behind layer tree, and the item clicked on
    model_ref = iface.layerTreeView().model()
    source_index = model_ref.index(0, 0)
    title = model_ref.data(index_ul)
    data = states.get(title, None)

    # if one of the two layers is clicked on
    if data:
        if model_ref.data(index_ul, Qt.CheckStateRole) == Qt.Checked:
            # filter buffers
            QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('buffers')[0].setSubsetString('"width" = ' + str(data[0]))
            # uncheck the other point layer
            item_list = model_ref.match(source_index, Qt.DisplayRole, data[1], 1, Qt.MatchExactly | Qt.MatchRecursive)
            if item_list:
                model_ref.setData(item_list[0], Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole) 
        else:
            QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('buffers')[0].setSubsetString('"width" = ' + str(data[2]))
            item_list = model_ref.match(source_index, Qt.DisplayRole, data[1], 1, Qt.MatchExactly | Qt.MatchRecursive)
            if item_list:
                model_ref.setData(item_list[0], Qt.Checked, Qt.CheckStateRole) 

    # inform about changes in item state
    model_ref.layoutChanged.emit()

    # reconnect handler
    iface.layerTreeView().model().dataChanged.connect(switch_buffers)

# not part of the function: connect handler 
iface.layerTreeView().model().dataChanged.connect(switch_buffers)
```

To use the code just copy&paste it into Python console.

Comment: thank you for this I can see that it will work however, I'm no programmer and have never used the Python Console but have activated it and copied the code, another however, I have multiple points layers (Leisure, Primary Schools, Health facilities etc.). I also have 2 buffer layers (which is why this got so complicated in the first place) - one centred on the site, the other from the development boundary, each has the same distances - 400m, 720m, 800m, 1Km etc. How would I manage the relationship between a site (point) layer and its respective buffers (could be 1:N buffers)?

Comment: @MarkPercival In this case the dict has to hold values for the other cases too, and the code has to be changed to loop over a set of layers being switched. If you like send me an email with the exact combinations of layers and buffer widths, its easier then to adapt the code to your requirements. Should only one point layer be visible, as in my code, or many points layers? To address this behaviour the script has to be changed too.